# SSH Keys, CYGWIN, BitBucket, Permission denied (publickey)

Tags: git, ssh, cygwin

I am trying to push an initial codebase to bitbucket. I have generated keys and BitBucket has my public key. When i run a GIT PUSH through CYGWIN

```
push -u origin --all
```

It just hangs.

I have tracked it down to the fact that the keys are not being handled correctly (see below)

When I run the following

```
ssh -vT user@bitbucket.org
```

I get the following output...

```
OpenSSH_6.6.1, OpenSSL 1.0.1g 7 Apr 2014
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh_config
debug1: Connecting to bitbucket.org [131.103.20.168] port 22.
debug1: Connection established.
debug1: identity file /home/user/.ssh/id_rsa type 1
debug1: identity file /home/user/.ssh/id_rsa-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /home/user/.ssh/id_dsa type -1
debug1: identity file /home/user/.ssh/id_dsa-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /home/user/.ssh/id_ecdsa type -1
debug1: identity file /home/user/.ssh/id_ecdsa-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /home/user/.ssh/id_ed25519 type -1
debug1: identity file /home/user/.ssh/id_ed25519-cert type -1
debug1: Enabling compatibility mode for protocol 2.0
debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_6.6.1
debug1: Remote protocol version 2.0, remote software version OpenSSH_5.3
debug1: match: OpenSSH_5.3 pat OpenSSH_5* compat 0x0c000000
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT sent
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT received
debug1: kex: server->client aes128-ctr hmac-md5 none
debug1: kex: client->server aes128-ctr hmac-md5 none
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_REQUEST(1024<3072<8192) sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_GROUP
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_INIT sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_REPLY
debug1: Server host key: RSA 97:8c:1b:f2:6f:14:6b:5c:3b:ec:aa:46:46:74:7c:40
debug1: Host 'bitbucket.org' is known and matches the RSA host key.
debug1: Found key in /home/user/.ssh/known_hosts:2
debug1: ssh_rsa_verify: signature correct
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS received
debug1: Roaming not allowed by server
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_REQUEST sent
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_ACCEPT received
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey
debug1: Next authentication method: publickey
debug1: Offering RSA public key: /home/user/.ssh/id_rsa
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey
debug1: Trying private key: /home/user/.ssh/id_dsa
debug1: Trying private key: /home/user/.ssh/id_ecdsa
debug1: Trying private key: /home/user/.ssh/id_ed25519
debug1: No more authentication methods to try.
Permission denied (publickey).
```

Note that the keys identified in the last few lines do not exist in the .ssh dir...

```
debug1: Trying private key: /home/user/.ssh/id_dsa
debug1: Trying private key: /home/user/.ssh/id_ecdsa
debug1: Trying private key: /home/user/.ssh/id_ed25519
```

Any ideas please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`ssh -vT user@bitbucket.org` won't ever work.

Only `git@bitbucket.org` can work.

As mentioned in "[Use the SSH protocol with Bitbucket](https://confluence.atlassian.com/display/BITBUCKET/Use+the+SSH+protocol+with+Bitbucket)", a valid ssh url for BitBucket repos looks like:

```
git@bitbucket.org:accountname/reponame.git
```

You can change the remote origin url with a:

```
cd /path/top/your/repo
git remote set-url origin git@bitbucket.org:accountname/reponame.git
```